# Какие ошибки присутствуют в данном "алгоритме"?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, рефакторинг

Есть рабочий кусок кода нуждающийся в рефакторинге. Он выполняет два ключевых этапа: `isDocumentHasChanges` - поиск изменений, и если есть то Update. 
Я не шибко специалист в плане налаживания кода, какие здесь есть косяки и как их можно исправить? (кроме именования переменных)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, DbList> entry : images.entrySet())
        {
            for(Object newImage : entry.getValue())
            {
                Map<String, Object> parameters = mappingpParameters((DataObject) newImage);
                Map<String, String> attributes = mappingAttributes((DataObject) newImage, importPars);

                if(!getURL((DataObject) newImage).equals(""))
                {
                    DataObject data = findDataById(attributes.get(ID), importPars);
                    File image = createImage(importPars, attributes, data);

                    if(!useImgImport || isDocumentHasChanges(image, data, parameters))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DbList forUpdate = docsForUpdate(image, newImage, attributes, parameters, importPars, data, useImgImport);

                            if (useImgImport)
                            {
                                update(forUpdate, importPars.getCollectionName(), data);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            logger.error("Current image has not saved", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из того, что видно

```java
for (Map.Entry<String, DbList> entry: images.entrySet()) {
  for (Object newImage: entry.getValue()) {
    if (!getURL((DataObject) newImage).equals("")) {
      // Вначале проверяем URL, а потом, при необходимости, создаем Map
      Map<String, Object> parameters = mappingpParameters((DataObject) newImage);
      Map<String, String> attributes = mappingAttributes((DataObject) newImage, importPars);

      DataObject data = findDataById(attributes.get(ID), importPars);
      File image = createImage(importPars, attributes, data);

     // Почему так, смотри ниже
      if (useImgImport && isDocumentHasChanges(image, data, parameters)) {
        try {
          DbList forUpdate = docsForUpdate(image, newImage, attributes, parameters, importPars, data, useImgImport);
          update(forUpdate, importPars.getCollectionName(), data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Current image has not saved", e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Или, если разнести условие `(useImgImport && isDocumentHasChanges(image, data, parameters))` то получится еще лучше

```java
if (useImgImport) {  // useImgImport нигде не модифицируется и ее можно проверить только раз
  for (Map.Entry<String, DbList> entry: images.entrySet()) {
    for (Object newImage: entry.getValue()) {
      if (!getURL((DataObject) newImage).equals("")) {
        // Вначале проверяем URL, а потом, при необходимости, создаем Map
        Map<String, Object> parameters = mappingpParameters((DataObject) newImage);
        Map<String, String> attributes = mappingAttributes((DataObject) newImage, importPars);

        DataObject data = findDataById(attributes.get(ID), importPars);
        File image = createImage(importPars, attributes, data);

        if (isDocumentHasChanges(image, data, parameters)) {
          try {
            DbList forUpdate = docsForUpdate(image, newImage, attributes, parameters, importPars, data, useImgImport);
            update(forUpdate, importPars.getCollectionName(), data);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Current image has not saved", e);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Пояснение по куску кода (try-catch выкинут для наглядности).

```
if (!useImgImport || isDocumentHasChanges(image, data, parameters)) {
  // (1)
  DbList forUpdate = docsForUpdate(image, newImage, attributes, parameters, importPars, data, useImgImport);  // (2)
  if (useImgImport) {
    // (3)
    update(forUpdate, importPars.getCollectionName(), data);
  }
}
```

- В `(1)` мы попадем в случае если `useImgImport = false` или были изменения в документе
- В `(2)` переменная `useImgImport` не изменяется
- В `(3)` мы попадем если `useImgImport = true`

Если объединить условия `(1)` и `(3)`, то `update()` выполнится при условии

```
(!useImgImport || isDocumentHasChanges) && useImgImport
```

или, раскрывая скобки

```
(!useImgImport && useImgImport) || (isDocumentHasChanges && useImgImport)
```

`(!useImgImport && useImgImport)` всегда равно `false` и на общее выражение не влияет. Остается только условие `(isDocumentHasChanges && useImgImport)`

Comment: Очень круто с useImgImport подметили, спасибо!!